Boot a kernel of debian installer with expert mode
I want to reinstall my VPS with the debian's official repository, instead of with the image provided by the VPS operator(I don't trust the VPS operator).
On original system I installed debian-installer by apt install debian-installer debian-installer-12-netboot-amd64, and taked the kernel that comes with debian-installer as a new grub booting entry.
When I reboot the VPS, it can automatically begin a fresh installing session, just like boot from a USB stick, so I can erase everything that offered by the operator.
Now I want to do more perfectly, i.e. to boot with expert install mode of the debian installer.
I guess the only way I can control the booting process of the installer's kernel, is to offer some kernel parameters in grub entry.
But I don't know what parameter I should specify, because these are NOT common kernel parameters those we can refer to the standard Linux docs.
What name and value of kernel parameters, can make the debian installer to boot into exert mode?
Or Where to find docs of this?
Thanks!


instead of with the image provided by the VPS operator(I don't trust the VPS operator).

Then you need to change the VPS operator. These guys run the virtualizer that your operating system runs in – they can literally do whatever they like with your RAM, including substituting URLs, making signature checks pass when they fail and so on.
So, yeah, you have a trust problem without a technical solution there.

Now I want to do more perfectly, i.e. to boot with expert install mode of the debian installer.

I didn't even know that was still a thing! I remember the advanced text-mode installer as being necessary mostly because the default installer didn't give one the choice over network setup and disk layout, but I don't think that is still an issue, and the current installer just can do as much as the "expert installer", maybe aside from Braille reader support (you'll want the default network setup for your VPS anyways, and even if you wanted to do manual setup, you can do that as soon as DHCP / IPv6 autoconf fails). I just played it through – I haven't found a single thing that I could do in the expert install that I can't in the default graphical installer, and which I'd want to do in a VM: Things like adding repositories, installing additional software or removing things are honestly best done with provisioning tools that you run on the clean installation (e.g., ansible), not through manual fiddling with dselect in the installer.
So make sure you're actually solving an issue there and not just making your life harder. Virtualized environments typically are perfectly auto-detectable without additional drivers (and if they aren't, you'll probably need the kernel from your VPS provider; see the unsolvable trust issue above).
However, should you prefer to do the installation via the serial console that your VPS provider might give you access to, sure, the DEBIAN_FRONTED=text parameter might be your method of choice. Note that the more common way is to upload a provisioning scheme (for example, a cloud-init configuration file). But this depends on the virtualization solution of your VPS provider.
In your use case, it's really more common to make a bootable image that supplies an SSH server, or that is fully preseeded to do the installation without manual interaction.

What name and value of kernel parameters, can make the debian installer to boot into exert mode? Or Where to find docs of this?

You'd find that by going to https://www.debian.org, clicking on "User Support / Getting help and documentation", clicking on the link in the dark grey box "documentation", clicking on "Installation Guide", then clicking on the architecture you have (64-bit ARM? 64-bit PC?), and then navigating to section 5, "Booting the Installation System"; and there, clicking on "5.3.2 Debian Installer Parameters".
